# Cocos2D - Layers' backgrounds turn to white for no reason

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

For some reason during loading one of the scenes in my game, the background to all scenes becomes white (that is, when using fadein/fadeout it does so to/from a white color. I've searched for the phrases ccc3 and ccc4 to no avail (ie I never changed anything manually). What could this be from? It starts when I load a certain scene and then affects everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was in LevelHelper, which I had used to load some objects in certain scenes. Apparently it gave the user the option of choosing a background colour, which proceeds to overwrite the black background (default C2D) with the colour you specify as soon as a level created by it is loaded (I used LevelHelper to create certain objects which I custom import into my scene).

So I changed the level backgrounds in LH to black and all was well. Alternately I could have refrained from importing the background colour.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in the dealloc method of your scenes. Sounds like you're maybe leaking scenes, which might keep the fade scene in memory and then it might just display a white screen. It's a guess but wouldn't be the first time that leaking scenes causes all kinds of weird issues.

Another thing to check is if you're using glClearColor to set the OpenGL background color.